# Connect managed stack server to AzureAD

Tags: ssh, azure-active-directory, centos7

I've got a group of managed stack server which are hosted on OVH.

Servers are out Microsoft and based on CentOS 7.

I want to make something like that but not with AzureVM:
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-ssh

I tried to connect it to Azure AD to authentificate ssh connections between my private domain and the hosted domain but I didn't joined the managed domain.

I followed this microsoft page
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-rhel-linux-vm

```
sudo realm discover <managed domain>
```

> returned me:

```
realm: No such realm found:  <managed domain>
```

Have you got an idea?